# Why is $k[x_1] \to A$ not finite and $\phi(y)=x_1+x_2$ finite?

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-geometry, ring-theory, commutative-algebra, modules

I was reading https://www.math.columbia.edu/~dejong/courses/deJongNotes.pdf. (Observe you don't have to look at the link as the question is self contained)

See Example 1 in the beginning. There I could not understand why $k[x_1] \to A$ (inclusion map) is not finite [$A$ is definitely finitely generated $k[x_1]$-module having generators $1, x_2$], where $A=k[x_1,x_2]/(x_1x_2-1)$. 
Moreover, I need help in understanding why $\phi: k[y] \to A$, $\phi(y)=x_1+x_2$ is finite?

**Edit:** From the comment (thanks to Samir Canning), I got that because of the variable $x_2$ and as $k[x_1]$ is a polynomial ring we have that $A$ is not finitely generated.
Can you help me in the 2nd question?

Comment: How do you get $x_2^2$ from your basis?

Comment: @SamirCanning thanks for the help.

Comment: The second question asks to prove that the ring extension $R=k[x_1+\frac{1}{x_1}]\subset k[x_1,\frac{1}{x_1}]=S$ is finite. In fact, $S=R+Rx_1+R\frac{1}{x_1}$ since $x_1^2=ax_1-1$ and $\frac{1}{x_1^2}=a\frac{1}{x_1}-1$, where $a=x_1+\frac{1}{x_1}$, so every integral power of $x_1$ can be written by using $x_1$ and $\frac{1}{x_1}$.